# Finding numbers of annotation in same coordinate in map view

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

Requirement is to find out the no. of annotation that exist in any particular coordinate. Is there any direct method which can be use to find out the no. of annotation at any points? or How can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your annotations are on a map. You need to define some bounding box around the coordinate you're interested in. From this coordinate bounding box you can calculate an `MKMapRect` and from that you can get the annotations inside using `annotationsInMapRect:`.

Alternately, you own the annotations so you can search whatever data structure you have the raw annotation data saved in.